# Проблема кодировки в apache cordova

Tags: html, кодировка, cordova

Делаю

```
cordova create MyApp com.app.myapp MyApp
cd MyApp.
cordova platform add android
```

Меняю в индексном файле через nodepad++

```
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Апач Кордова</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Соединение с девайсом</p>
            <p class="event received">Девай загружен</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

На выходе получаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно исправить проблему с кодировкой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто добавьте мета тег

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```